# WP - How to check if parent of page is a frontpage

Tags: wordpress

I'm using static page and I would like to check if current page is under frontpage/post page.
For example:
www.example.com/blog - is set to post page in Settings->Reading
How can I check if www.example.com/blog/some_page is under blog- post page? I can't check it by name becouse it doesn't have to be named blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the ID with `get_option()`.

```
if (get_option('page_on_front') == $post->post_parent) {
    echo "parent is start page";
}
```